# Can't remove VLC Plug-in from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, windows-7-x64, vlc, mkv

Every time I try to stream or download an .mkv file the page stops responding and Chrome asks me if I want to "kill the page". I tried disabling the VLC plug-in from `chrome://plugins` but the "VLC Web Plugin" does not exist in my list of plug-ins.  Can anyone help me with this problem? I used to be able to play & download .mkv's without issue. I'm not sure what has changed.